# Edit template Form sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a list template from a content type and made a custom form using Sharepoint Designer.

I now need to edit the form - I need to change some of the wording I put on it.

Is there anyway I can do this as i’ve spent the last few days looking online yet can’t see anything that can help me :-(

Comment: If you've customized edit form using SharePoint Designer - why you can't edit this form by the same way through SP Designer?

Answer (score 0):

The same form can be edited in SharePoint Designer multiple times. Make the changes and create your list template again.

Comment: @Raf & Nanddeep I’m aware of that however the list template I have created is now attached to 45 different lists so creating a new list template isn’t an option - unless i’m missing something ?? I’ve tried editing the form from the original list that I created which I then made into a template however I’m getting the following error message “the server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source. Check the format and content of your query and try again’